# change first responders in uitableviewcell textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I am developing an app using storyboard. There is a custom class for `UITableViewCell` (`MoneyEntryTableViewCell`) which contains `UITextField`.

**Question:**
I want to move the focus to other text fields, added in other cells, as I press Previous/Next (`<>`) in my Keyboard.

In .h file

```
@interface MoneyEntryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textAmount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblmemId; // Hidden 

@end
```

In .m file

```
@implementation MoneyEntryTableViewCell

@synthesize lblMemName,textAmount;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

In Controller, this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath func...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MoneyEntryTableViewCell *cell = (MoneyEntryTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UserAmountCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
         cell = [[MoneyEntryTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UserAmountCell"] ;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UILabel     *lblname  = (UILabel *)    [cell lblMemName];
    lblname.tag =100;
    lblname.text = [[self.MembersList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

    UILabel     *lblId  = (UILabel *)    [cell lblmemId];
    lblId.tag =101;
    lblId.text = [[self.MembersList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

    UITextField *txtfield = (UITextField *)[cell textAmount];
    txtfield.tag = 200 + indexPath.row;
    txtfield.placeholder = @"0.00";
    txtfield.delegate = self;
    [txtfield addTarget:self  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    txtfield.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saif Thanks.

I post my code here.

Declare in interface.  `UITextField *activeField;`

```
- (void)Previous:(id)sender
{
    [self switchToNextField:NO];
}

- (void)Next:(id)sender
{
    [self switchToNextField:YES];
}
```

Do your own logic to disable and enable previous & next, By tag you set in `UITextfield`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    activeField = textField;
    [self.PrevButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.NextButton setEnabled:YES];
    if(textField.tag ==200)
        [self.PrevButton setEnabled:NO];
    else if (textField.tag == 200 + [self.MembersList count] - 1) //self.MembersList table Source.
    {
        [self.NextButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;

}
```

Pass **next = YES** if you want next text field to become active.
Pass **next = NO** if you want previous text field to become active

```
- (void)switchToNextField:(BOOL)next
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)activeField.tag);
    if(next)
    {
        float tag = activeField.tag - 200;
        NSIndexPath *indexPathUserName = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tag + 1 inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tblVwSpltList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathUserName];
        UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:activeField.tag + 1];
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        float tag = activeField.tag - 200;
        NSIndexPath *indexPathUserName = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tag - 1 inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblVwSpltList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathUserName];
        UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:activeField.tag - 1];
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create references to the textfields you want to jump between. When you set up the cell, grab the reference to the textfield and set it. For this example, I'm assuming I have a `NSMutableArray *textFieldArray` already declared.

```
// within cellForRowAtIndexPath
self.textField1 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
[self.textField1.setDelegate:self];

if (![textFieldArray containsObject:self.textField1]) {
    [textFieldArray addObject:self.textField1];
}
```

This way, when you recognize the "next" button is pressed, jump to the next index in the textFieldArray and make that text field the first responder. To do this you can either keep track of which index is the first responder, or iterate through the array to find the one that is active...

```
for (int i = 0; i < [textFieldArray count]; i++) {
    if ([[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i] isFirstResponder]) {
        if (i == [textFieldArray count]-1) // last item in array - dismiss
            [[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i] resignFirstResponder];
        else // go to next item
            [[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i+1] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do if by keeping the references of textfields in an array

```
- (void)switchToNextField:(BOOL)next
{
    //pass next = YES if you want next text filed to become active
    //pass next = NO if you want previos text filed to become active

    for (id object in arrayOfTextFields) { //loop through all text fields
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
            if ([textFieldObject isFirstResponder]) { //check if it is in editing state
                float indexOfCurrentField = [arrayOfTextFields indexOfObject:textFieldObject];
                if (next) {
                    indexOfCurrentField++;//if next button clicked
                }
                else
                {
                    indexOfCurrentField-- ;//if previous button clicked
                }
                if (indexOfCurrentField < 0)
                    indexOfCurrentField = 0; //this will solve the previous button crash
                if (indexOfCurrentField < arrayOfTextFields.count) {
                    UITextField *nextTextField = [arrayOfTextFields objectAtIndex:indexOfCurrentField];
                    [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Click Next button,Why  last textfield in table become first responder . At first time click previous button it crash for duplicate index, but i resolve it by disable previous button by textfield tag.

Comment: When you click Next button , call `[self switchToNextField:YES];`, and when you click previous button call  `[self switchToNextField:NO];`

Comment: Thanks Saif. I get same problem again. that moves to last field in table. AnyWay I Get new Idea and Solve My issue. Thanks Again.

Comment: You are welcome, The problem might be, improper references of text fields in an `arrayOfTextFields `, make sure that the indexes of textfields in array are correct.